# Cannot find bootable device - can't boot from USB - can't update BIOS - no grub

Tags: boot, grub, uefi, bios

I was wondering if anyone could give me some advice on how to proceed with this faulty installation.
I have Dell Inspiron 15 5570 that had a while ago Linux Mint installation on it. The installation wasn’t good, I didn’t use the laptop for a while and when I got back to it and wanted to set it up properly, I couldn’t do anything that I wanted.

The problem is that the Bios won’t accept usb devices plugged in. In boot options it only shows “ubuntu” and “ MocksbSet”. Adding a boot option doesn’t change a thing.

Ubuntu option is set to look for boot in /EFI/ubuntu/ and I can't change that either.

Disabling the Secure Boot and enabling Legacy Boot options doesn’t do anything. Basically, any changes I make to BIOS are not persisted. I tried flashing the BIOS but that didn’t work either. BIOS  remains on same version .
I tried clearing CMOS but it didn’t help whatsoever.

When I boot my laptop I manage to get to the Grub Rescue prompt. I tried listing my drives(including usb live installation which is visible from there) and setting up the proper one in prefix and root, but running

```
insmod normal
```

Or

```
insmod linux
```

Doesn’t do anything. Calling normal or linux commands afterward just returns:

```
normal command not found.
```

All the diagnostic tests on the laptop pass without any problems.
What I tried doing after that is to take the ssd and hook it up externally to a computer and install Linux there. I installed ubuntu twice, with different partitioning and boot locations but when I put the hard drive back in the laptop and start the system, I can’t even get it to recognise hard drive as a bootable option. The only things I can do is to test the hardware, see boot options and that’s it.

Is there any way I can get grub at least :D
Has anyone come along a problem like this or if anyone has an idea what I could try next, it would be really appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an option to "Select an UEFI file as trusted" in BIOS? I had a similar issue after upgrading BIOS with Debian installed. Had to set up BIOS password first, and only after that I could specify the file to boot. It was EFI > debian > shimx64.efi. Yours should be in EFI > ubuntu > shimx64.efi.